# How to make multiple sort with perl?

Tags: perl

I have this snippet, which sorts values, e.g. Title2 2005; Title2 1998; Title3 1994; etc by decade and is working flawlessly. But I need to add additional sorting of the already sorted decades - first numerically descending and then alphabetically ascending. If I use the second_sort subroutine I get an error 'Can't locate object method via package'. Do I have a small error in my code or my logic is totally wrong and I should seek another approach.

Thanks.

```
use autodie;
use strict;
use warnings;
use HTML::TreeBuilder;


my %sort = ();
push (@{$sort{$decade}}, $t );

for my $decade ( sort { $b <=> $a } keys %sort ) {

    my @td = map { $_->as_HTML("<>&","\t",{}) }  second_sort( @{$sort{$decade}} );
}

sub second_sort {
    my @sorted = map { @$_ }
            sort {  $b->[1] <=> $a->[1] || lc $a->[0] cmp lc $b->[0]  }
            map {
                my ($title, $year) = ($_->as_trimmed_text =~ /(.*?)\((\d+)\).*/);
                [$title, $year];
                } @_;
    return @sorted;
}
```

Comment: I don't get this error when I execute it (after removing the line `push (@{$sort{$decade}}, $t );`). look for the error somewhere else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are missing the use of the HTML::Element module to provide 'as_trimmed_text'.

Comment: Yes. After some testing it seems that the new element is what I'm missing. Is it correct to add this line my '$tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content(@_);' at the beginning and from there to do the sorting or I should add this line somewhere between the sorting. Thanks for your assistance.